# VBA connect to {dbname}-ondemand.sql.azuresynapse.net

Tags: vba, azure-synapse

Is it possible to connect to Synapse SQL (i.e. {dbname}-ondemand.sql.azuresynapse.net) from Excel/VBA?

I've tried using the ODBC connection string suggested in this article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/connect-overview#supported-drivers-and-connection-strings

But I am getting the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, of course it's possible. Follow the instructions below and tou should be in business in no time at all.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-excel

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for a VBA solution, but your suggestion got me thinking again and I finally figured it out. Turns out I was using wrong connection string, it should have been this one - Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive;User ID=myUserName;Use Encryption for Data=true;

Comment: Excel+VBA in Excel works fine with Synapse. I did it a couple years ago. It works almost identical to Excel+VBA and SQL Server.